# Process Daily Logs from Cloudwatch using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I dont have much code to show.

I want to process all cloudwatch logs that are generated in last 1 day using lambda.
I want to execute lambda 6 am in the morning to extract some information from cloudwatch logs that are generated on previous day and put it in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your 6 AM idea, you could also use a CloudWatch Logs subscription filter and trigger a Lambda function to process and store the log entries as described in a step-by-step example here [Example 2: Subscription filters with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample).

Or even easier and without duplicating the data to a database: [Analyzing log data with CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a lot of Lambda functions and each has a CloudWatch Log Group.

You can try the [CloudWatch Log Group subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html), with this feature you can stream your logs into any support destinations such as **Lambda**.

[image: cwlogs-subscription-filter-lambda]

Before that, you should prepare a Lambda function that has functionalities to help you to put your extracted data into **DynamoDB table**.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aws-dynamodb-insert-data-using-aws-lambda/